# Custom-fit Android app: auto-update and always-on?

Tags: android, auto-update

I'm trying to develop an app that would normally be considered to be malware, but the customer's demands are very specific and logical. We have around 50-100 cheapset Android phones that are bolted down, plugged in, and the app is supposed to send some of the sensor data via tcp to a remote server. It sounds simple enough, but there are two features that I struggle with (since I'm not an experienced Android developer, and have never rooted a phone):

#1 The app should be always on. If it crashes, server should get the error report (stack trace), and the app should be restarted after 10 minutes one more time before giving up. Also, the OS could theoretically kill the app (although I did my best to minimize the memory usage). I'd like to somehow handle that as well.

#2 It would be great if the app could be remotely updated, or auto-updated, with no user interaction whatsoever (since there is no conventional user).

To implement #1, I see no other solution than to root the phone (AlarmsManager doesn't seem to work as I expected, and adding another application to take care of the first one just feels wrong). Is there anything I'm missing?

I don't know how to approach implementing feature #2 at all. If I put the app on the market and check the "keep this application always up to date" checkbox while installing it, will that work? I fear that the auto-update would not occur while the service is running, and even if it did, that the OS would not restart the service after installing the update (unless feature #1 is implemented). If I programatically download the latest .apk and open it, I still need the user to click the "Install" button. I'm even considering implementing the updateable part in some scripting language.

Is there a solution to these problems within the limits of Android API?

EDIT: Thank you all for your answers, you've been very helpful. It seems that the only way to make Android behave as a non-user piece of hardware is to root it. That's the only way to do silent auto-updates. Always on can then be implemented by enabling cron (AlarmManager apparently doesn't fire the event in case of service termination via crash, but it could be used by another trivial, non-crashable service to keep the first one running).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1 you can use an foreground service. I don't know how often you need to get sensor data, but what's the problem with AlarmManager? I don't see how rooting could help with #1 though. You can't really do #2 without rooting or building your firmware. If you install your app as a system app (in `/system/app`) you can use a hidden `PackageManager` to silently install the new version. Using Market/Play autoupdate should work as well, but you have no way to control the update schedule. And, yes, it won't restart your service, but if you use AlaramManager, this shouldn't be a issue.

All in all, stock Android is not exactly an embedded system that gives you full control, so depending on how much time/effort you are willing to spend, you might want to customize it somewhat (or find a custom ROM that gets close to your requirements).

Comment: AlarmManager: I set up the alarm for ELAPSED_REALTIME (once a minute) and it fired as long as my app was running, but stopped firing when I crashed the app (by throwing an exception) or killed it with task manager. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Are you sure GooglePlay will kill my app just to update it? Its service runs a sleep-check-send loop. If that is the case, and no user is required to click a button, that that's exactly what I'm looking for (but I couldn't find any information about this, and I'm not about to upload something just to check and see).

Comment: i'm sorry to say, google play will not kill your application to update, you have to do it yourself. regarding alarmmanager -- you have to write a service, not plain application, and mark that service as STICKY, so the system will know it's supposed to keep running.

Comment: If you force close/kill an Android process, alarms will be cleared. This is how Android works. Sleep-check-whatever loop is antipattern that wastes battery, so you should definitely avoid it. The Market/Play behaviour is indeed undocumented, but how hard is it to upload a test app to try it out? You can always unpublish it later.

Comment: How is while (true) sleep(1000) wasting any more battery than a 1000ms timer event? I'm not concerned about battery life here, but I fail to see the difference. And what about while (true) lock(mutex) mutex.wait(1000) with occasional mutex.notify() from another thread?

Comment: If you use AlarmManager, your app does not have to be running at all. Additionally, Android can choose to restart your service at any time, to your sleep loops are not guaranteed to run as you expect them.

Answer (score 0):

Re: question #2, there are a few `open-source` (licensed under the Apache Software License 2.0) options you may check and see how it works.

1. https://github.com/lazydroid/auto-update-apk-client is the android client for the auto update service (i'm affiliated with), which is small, easy to implement and supports silent updates on rooted devices.
2. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater is written by Mark Murphy, however it might require you to run your own update server and I'm not sure about silent updates.

Comment: Thank you, I will give them a look.